# Combobox drop down showing up in other sheets

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a combo box drop down with search suggestions, made from code here:

http://trumpexcel.com/2013/10/excel-drop-down-list-with-search-suggestions/

It works very well, but when I'm on another sheet and pressing "Enter", the search field randomly pops up in the sheet[image]

It's not even the full box, just the blue field

Any insights on disabling it? The only success I've had is turning calculation to manual, but the workbook needs automatic calculation

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue with my own VBA version of a smart search bar. How I fixed it was by doing the following:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If ComboBox1.Value = "" Then Exit Sub '<------ Problem solved.
    ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "DropDownList"
    Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
End Sub
```

OR

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim SheetWithComboBox As Worksheet: Set SheetWithComboBox = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    If ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name <> SheetWithComboBox.Name Then
        ComboBox1.Visible = False
    Else: ComboBox1.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If i have something entered into the combo box the blue field pops up in other sheets randomly as well

Comment: the blue field pops up whenever i paste something too, very strange

Comment: Oh hmm.. Maybe..Maybe try this. I don't know if this will fix it for you... I'll update my answer, give the code a shot.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, when I put it into workbook code it says object required. I tried to mod the code to fit my sheet names but it doesnt work either :(

Comment: I figured it out! I used your logic and set the combo box macro accordingly. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

@Tyeler

Thanks for your help, your thinking helped me think of a way

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_change()
 Dim sht1 As Worksheet
 Set sht1 = Worksheets("xxx")

 If ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = sht1.Name Then

ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "DropDownList"
Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
Call macro1
Else: Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that, at least for me, works for all sheets.

```
Private Sub Combobox_Get_Focus() 

    ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "DropDownList" 
    Me.ComboBox1.DropDown 

End Sub
```

Comment: Where's your solution?